# How to build a Map with properties/variable values of a Object laying in a List/Set

Tags: java, apache-commons-beanutils

im trying to find ways how i can create a Map with certain property/variable values of a object. My english is far from being perfect but i will try to go into details.

Lets say we have a simple Java object with these three variables and their public getters and setters

```
Integer id
String name
String street
```

Now i will collect/put some of these Objects in a List or Set (lets assume that all variable values will be unqiue). What i want to do next is to build a Map with the id and name of all Objects in the List/Set.
Of course i could just iterate the List everytime and build a Map but does anybody know a, lets say more elegant, solution? I ve seen that Java 8 is offering things like Collector's and/or Filter but im searching for a Java 7 solution.
I also read apache commons BeanUtils could help (with using reflection under the hood) but i cant find a example for my use case so far...

As a additional info: I m not allowoed to add a new ext lib like a google/guava :-/ BeanUtils (and some other commons) would exist already...

Does anybody have a idea?

Comment: Look at the second answer though. It is using Google Collections

Comment: If you want to build a `Map<Integer, List<Object>>` using Java 7 I think Guava's `ListMultimap` is the way to go.

Comment: Im not allowed to add another external lib to the project im working on :-/. BeanUtils and some other commons exists already...

Comment: In that case, I think that the answer is there is no nice way. You just have to iterate the `List` and build the `Map` as you do.